# Custom URL for post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slug

I have problem with creating custom link for custom post type. I have tried many solutions including many plugins but there is nothing yet that helped me.

I have `post_product` type which has url:
**website.com/products/product-name**

I need to have:
**website.com/category/product-name**

I almost completed this job but other pages (post type: post, pages) and not working (error 404). Do you have any idea how to make it work?

My code for registering post type:

```
function post_product() {
$args = array(
  'label' => 'Products',
    'name' => 'products',
    'singular_name' => 'product',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-carrot',        
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
        'author')
    );
register_post_type( 'post_product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'post_product' );
```

Comment: can you provide us the code of register post type and register taxonomy?

Comment: I have added code in first post

Comment: Anyone? I really need this to work